# How to get Gallai-Edmonds decomposition of a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In graph theory, the Gallai–Edmonds decomposition is a partition of the vertices of a graph into subsets satisfying certain properties. Describe it in more detail. [from here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture8.pdf)

[image]

[image]

To get the maximum matching of a graph, we just use the built-in standard function **FindIndependentEdgeSet**, and now I want to get the **above decomposition** of a graph. How do I get Gallai–Edmonds decomposition?

From the Wikipedia entry on Gallai–Edmonds decomposition, they can **be found** using the **blossom algorithm**. [Wolfram Codes of The Blossom Algorithm for Maximum Matching](https://www.demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheBlossomAlgorithmForMaximumMatching/#popup1)

I don't have a good idea right now.

```
  g = Graph[{1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7}, {UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
   UndirectedEdge[1, 5], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 4], 
   UndirectedEdge[4, 5], UndirectedEdge[3, 6], UndirectedEdge[4, 6], 
   UndirectedEdge[3, 7], 
   UndirectedEdge[4, 7]}];
 FindIndependentEdgeSet[g]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not particularly efficient, but the following should do the trick:

```
maxMatchingSize[g_] := Length[FindIndependentEdgeSet[g]]
egDecomposition[g_] := Module[{vertexList, max, d, a, c},
  vertexList = VertexList[g];
  max = maxMatchingSize[g];
  d = Select[vertexList, maxMatchingSize[VertexDelete[g, #]] == max &];
  a = Complement[AdjacencyList[g, Alternatives @@ d], d];
  c = Complement[vertexList, d, a];
  <|"D" -> d, "A" -> a, "C" -> c|>
]
```

See this function in the Wolfram Function Repository as GallaiEdmondsDecomposition:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/GallaiEdmondsDecomposition/